# Not able to call anything in KYDrawer DrawerController

Tags: swift

I Have created a Drawer view using [KYDrawerController](https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController), It is a `UIViewController` with `tableview` with some contents, I'm calling an API to fill in the tableView, but I'm not able to display or call that API function inside the Drawer ViewController.

This is my Code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class DrawerViews: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let categoriesUrl = "https://stagecmsbmncapi.projectpresent.biz/client/categories/"

    public var tag_Names: String{ return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") ?? "" }


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCategories()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func getCategories() {
        Alamofire.request(categoriesUrl).responseJSON { (response) in
            if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
                var jsonResult = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(jsonResult)
                if let da = jsonResult["result"].arrayObject
                {
                    self.data = da as! [[String : AnyObject]]

                }

            }
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return 1
        case 1:
            return 2
        case 2 :
            return 5
        default:
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! NameCell
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! CatgoryCell
            return cell1
        case 2 :
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: indexPath) as! SupportCell
            return cell
        default :
            print("Defaults")
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return 100
        case 1:
            return 60
        case 2 :
            return 60
        default:
            return 700
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call that getCategories() Function in ViewDidAppear.